# Showing 8 weeks in a jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've seen examples where you can have jQuery UI Datepicker show two months, side-by-side, but is there any way to get the Datepicker to seamlessly display eight consecutive weeks, not with two months side-by-side but with eight weeks stacked on top of each other, as if a month were eight weeks long? I want to make sure I know whether it's possible or not (or reasonably easy) before I go writing my own thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hack up the jQuery UI datepicker's code (probably would have to change the JS as well as CSS) to make it work, but, **no**, it does not offer this out of the box.